# infamous Two Div's next to each other

Tags: html, css, facebook

I know there are a lot of questions about this, and I've tried many solutions but I can't get it to work. I have two divs in a facebook canvas page(810px), and I want them to display next to each other. Currently one is on top of the other. Here is my code:

```
<div class="tab_content tab1" >
 <div id="dialerdiv1" style="float: left; margin-right: 405px;">
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"
    src="thesource"
    width="301"
    height="401"
    id="popUpSwf"
    name="popUpSwf"
    quality="high"
    border="none"
    allowscriptaccess="always"
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    scale="noscale"
    menu="false"
    flashvars="..." />
 </div>
 <div id="dialerdiv2" style="float: right; width: 405px;">
      <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"
      src="thesource"
      width="301"
      height="401"
      id="popUpSwf"
      name="popUpSwf"
      quality="high"
      border="none"
      allowscriptaccess="always"
          pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
      scale="noscale"
      menu="false"
      flashvars="..." />            
 </div>
</div>
```

How do I get those two inside divs next to each other? Also, I tried using a table, and it works, but Firefox shifts those td cells to the outside of the canvas area and I cannot get them centered (only firefox)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the parent div `<div class="tab_content tab1">` has more than 810px available in width then the following code should work perfectly fine.

```
<div class="tab_content tab1">
    <div id="dialerdiv1" style="float: left; width: 405px;">
        <embed ... />
    </div>
    <div id="dialerdiv2" style="float: left; width: 405px;">
        <embed ... />            
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok it didn't really work, but you put me in the right direction. Firstly, #dialerdiv2 I set to float: right; (but I'm sure that is what you meant) and I set the main div to width: 810px; and the two inside divs to width: 405px each. What is the use of the 3rd div(style="clear: both;")? Cuase I took it out and made no difference? But thanks, you really helped me out a lot

Comment: No, I mean to use `float: left` on `#dialerdiv2`. The 3rd div is what I always use to avoid clutter. So, use firebug or any inspector to check if there is any extra padding/margin anywhere like the other answer suggests, and that the parent div width is sufficient to contain the child divs - try reducing the width of the child divs.

Answer (score 2):

if you change the width of second div it should work.

```
<div id="dialerdiv2" style="float: right; width: 370px;">
```

also it should work like this

```
         <div id="dialerdiv1" style="float: left; margin-right: 390px;">
            ......
         </div>
         <div id="dialerdiv2" style="float: right; width: 390px;">
            ........
         </div>
```

The problem comes from the size of your divs and the available space. Play a little bit with them and you will figure out what is the correct values to use

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the body margin and padding?

```
body{margin:0;padding:0}
```